# Why can't I add a phpMyAdmin username and password?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, macos-sierra

I am using MAMP and I changed my web server folder to a folder on my desktop. I downloaded the latest version of phpMyAdmin and placed it in the folder. When I navigated to it using `localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin` I am logged in automatically. I created a `config.inc.php` file from the sample but there is no option to add a username or password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [refer to the documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#a-word-about-users), in particular it explains that phpMyAdmin doesn't have user accounts. The user accounts you use to authenticate actually are MySQL accounts, so to add a new user you'll have to add a MySQL user. You can do that from the phpMyAdmin "User accounts" tab (called "Privileges" in older versions).